# yii framework not working in mac

Tags: php, yii, xampp, htdocs

When creating a project in `applications/xampp/htdocs` using the yii framework in terminal, it's showing an error as `permission denied`. I can create projects in all other folders.

Here is the terminal command I've written:

```
% php yii/framework/yiic.php webapp /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/pjt_1
```

The error shown was

```
PHP Error[2]: mkdir(): Permission denied
    in file /Applications/yii/framework/console/CConsoleCommand.php at line 457
#0 /Applications/yii/framework/console/CConsoleCommand.php(457): mkdir()
#1 /Applications/yii/framework/console/CConsoleCommand.php(455): WebAppCommand->ensureDirectory()
#2 /Applications/yii/framework/console/CConsoleCommand.php(366): WebAppCommand->ensureDirectory()
#3 /Applications/yii/framework/cli/commands/WebAppCommand.php(96): WebAppCommand->copyFiles()
#4 /Applications/yii/framework/console/CConsoleCommandRunner.php(68): WebAppCommand->run()
#5 /Applications/yii/framework/console/CConsoleApplication.php(92): CConsoleCommandRunner->run()
#6 /Applications/yii/framework/base/CApplication.php(162): CConsoleApplication->processRequest()
#7 /Applications/yii/framework/yiic.php(34): CConsoleApplication->run()
```

What should I do to allow access to xampp folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the pjt_1 folder and select "Get Info".

In the popup window select the "Sharing and Permissions" tab.

If it doesn't say this already, as an experiment, change the privilege next to "everyone" to "Read & Write".  Then try creating your Yii application from the terminal again.

Comment: i couldn't change the permission :( the access is denied.. but ur answr is right.. thanks 4 the informtn :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo yii/framework/yiic webapp pjt_1
```